# Negative index (-1) at each click

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, target

I have a little problem with my code:

```
 public GameObject[] Letters;
 Randomizer WordsChildIndex;
 Transform[] LetterInteract;
 void Start () 
 {
    WordsChildIndex = new Randomizer(0, 29, true);
    int ChildIndex = WordsChildIndex.getRandom();
    Words.setCurrentChildIndex(ChildIndex);
    LetterInteract = Letters[ChildIndex].GetComponentsInChildren<Transform();
    for(int i = 0; i < LetterInteract.Length; i++)
    {
        LetterInteract[i].gameObject.AddComponent<CircleCollider2D>();
        LetterInteract[i].gameObject.GetOrAddComponent<MouseEventSystem>().MouseEvent += CheckLetterSound;

    }
}   

private void CheckLetterSound(GameObject target, MouseEventType type)
{
    if(type == MouseEventType.CLICK)
    {
        int targetIndex = System.Array.IndexOf(LetterInteract, target);
        Debug.Log(targetIndex);
    }
}
```

From the code, I notice that I add the Circle Collider component to random generated objects.

The problem is that for every click the targetIndex is -1. For example, a click on the object with index 2, the targetIndex must be 2 and so on.

Can anyone tell me where the error in my code is?

Comment: When you just want to have the correct index just use

`int targetIndex = System.Array.IndexOf(LetterInteract, target)+1;`

List and Arrays start at index 0.

so:

Obj1 -> Ind0; Obj2 -> Ind1; Obj3 -> Ind2

So when you click Object2 you get Ind1

Comment: @TheSkimek That's not the problem here. `IndexOf` returns -1 when there is no match.

Comment: Yeh i misunderstood the problem, sorry. 
The Question is already answered

Comment: It seems like you're looking for a `GameObject` in an array of `Transform`.
Simply look for the transform in your array and it should work

Answer (score 4):

From what I can see you want the `Transform` object with `gameObject` equals `target`.

If so, you need to use `Linq`, first you find the `Transform` whose `gameObject` equals `target`, and then get the index of it.

```
var transform = LetterInteract.FirstOrDefault(x => x.gameObject == target);
var targetIndex = Array.IndexOf(LetterInteract, transform);
```

Another option is:

```
var targetIndex = Array.FindIndex(x => x.gameObject == target);
```

Comment: I believe he could also do `int targetIndex = System.Array.IndexOf(LetterInteract, target.transform);`
I don't think it's worth creating another answer for that so if you want to add it

Comment: guys, I still have a little problem. When I try to do this:
 LetterInteract = Letters[ChildIndex].GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();
for (int i = 0; i < LetterInteract.Length; i++)
        {
            LetterInteract[i].gameObject.AddComponent<CircleCollider2D>();
            LetterInteract[i].gameObject.GetOrAddComponent<MouseEventSystem>().MouseEvent += CheckLetterSound;           
        }

Comment: the problem is that I also take parent, so he puts the collider and event to the parent